# Admissible ordinals...

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

a little question about admissible sets: 
Is every $\mathfrak{M}$-admissible ordinals an admissible ordinal ? where $\mathfrak{M}$ is a 
$L$-structure over $L=\{R_1,\dots,R_k \}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, admissibility relativizes downward. For a transitive structure to be admissible, it must be amenable, and satisfy $\Sigma_0$-collection. Both are conditions that keep holding if you "remove parameters". This is obvious for amenability. For collection, a little argument is needed. If you have access to Devlin's "Constructibility" book, this is at the beginning of II.7. (Sorry, I do not currently have time to flesh out details.)

Comment: Unrelated: is your name supposed to be a pig-Latinization of "Barwise"?

Answer (score 2):

Removing this question from the unanswered list:

> Yes, admissibility relativizes downward. For a transitive structure to be admissible, it must be amenable, and satisfy $\Sigma_0$-collection. Both are conditions that keep holding if you "remove parameters". This is obvious for amenability. For collection, a little argument is needed. If you have access to Devlin's "Constructibility" book, this is at the beginning of II.7. ([Andres Caicedo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170380/admissible-ordinals#comment391544_170380))

Comment: (Yes, I assume the question was in the context of Barwise's book, where urelements are allowed, which makes the arguments somewhat more involved than in the pure sets case.)